# Determine the less value of $n\in\mathbb{N}$ for $S_{n}$ having an element of order $200$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

I'm having trouble in solving this problem; here is my attempt:

If $\sigma\in S_{n}$ ($S_{n}$ is the symmetric group) has order $200$, then, there exists $\sigma_{1},...,\sigma_{r}$ disjoint cycles with respective lengths of $l_{1},...,l_{r}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\sigma=\sigma_{1}...\sigma_{r}$ and $lcm(l_{1}...l_{r})=200$. As $200=2^{3}\cdot 5^{2}$, there must exist $i,j\in\{1,...,r\}$ (equal or different) such that $l_{i}$ is a multiple of $2^{3}$ and $l_{j}$ is a multiple of $5^{2}$. So, my aim will be to find the less $n$ where I can find that this last condition stands...and... after this disconnected ideas, I am quite lost.

I would appreciate so much some guidance on this question... Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: @NickyHekster thank you so much for your quick response! but, I don't really get it... I don't see how in $S_{16}$ is there a $200$ order element... I have been thinking a little more and I have seen that definitely in $S_{33}$ we have the wanted element, as we can find disjoint cycles of lengths 8 and 25 that would provide us with the element we want by composition of both of them... but in $S_{16}$? Could you give me a little more of explanation? I'm so sorry for not understanding it, hope it doesn't bother you. thanks!

Comment: I think you are right @rubikman23, $n=33$ will do and nothing smaller will provide an element of order $200$.

Comment: I do apologize, $n=16$ is not the right answer it is $33$ indeed: an $8$-cycle times a $25$-cycle. I was to quick. Mixed up with an element of order $10$.